# I want change required's message in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want change required message to my custom message.

My model ->

```
class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    tel_number = models.CharField(max_length=25,validators=[number_regex])
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.teacher)
```

When I empty the empty form, it gives an default error  **"This field may not be blank."**. i want change this message.

```
class TeacherInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=TeacherProfile
        fields="__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            'bio': {"error_messages": {"required": "My custom error"}},
            'address': {"error_messages": {"required": "My custom error"}},
        }
```

But nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for that message is `blank`:

```
    extra_kwargs = {
        'bio': {"error_messages": {
            "required": "My custom error",
            "blank": "My custom error",
        }},
        'address': {"error_messages": {
            "required": "My custom error",
            "blank": "My custom error",
        }},
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, actually you are trying to change the default error of `required` instead of `blank`.

The difference between required and blank error constraint, when you don't send the mandatory field inside your payload then required constraint used to send error for that field and when you send the field with blank value ("") and blank value is not acceptable in your model (blank=False) then blank error constaint is used.

So, if you want just to change your blank default message then you can do it as

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'bio': {"error_messages": {"blank": "My blank custom error"}},
    'address': {"error_messages": {"blank": "My blank custom error"}},
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is completly depend on your use case and product requirement, for model fields you have to that in extra_kwargs but if you specify any serialzer field manually then you can add there as an function parameter as
`format = serializers.CharField(error_messages={"required": "My custom error", "blank": "My blank custom error"})`